# Read XML Java EE

Tags: java, xml

I need to read the XML in the site:[URL](http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel=SUZB5).

I saw lots of API's to use with XML but I didn't see anyone example receiving XML from the URL external site. How Can I do this?

after that I need to read it, I'll need store the values from XML in each variable in my code. Is There a 'Get' command to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: If the XML Schema is static, you can use SimpleXML and let the framework do the binding for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String nome;
    Element root;
    Element papel;
    Node node;
    URL url = new URL(
            "http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel=SUZB5");
    SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
    Document document = reader.read(url);
    root = document.getRootElement();
    System.out.println("" + root.asXML());
    papel = root.element("Papel");
    System.out.println("Nome:" + papel.attributeValue("Nome"));
    nome = papel.attributeValue("Nome");
```

Use this code with dom4j xml parser to parse xml return.
Try this example in eclipse or something just put it in your main method and run.  It will print out xml string that is returned.  All you need to do is use the dom4j xml parser to pull out the values you need and store them in your variables.  Make sure you add the dom4j jars.

Comment: Thank you!! It was very helpful, I'm trying to get the data from XML to my variable but I'm not able to do... Do you have some example?

Comment: I edited my post hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, now it's clear! Thanks!!